# Vaadin with Instagram API

Tags: java, vaadin, instagram

To use my app, the user must log in to their instagram account and give my app permission to access their information.

Once this is done, a URL with a code attached to the back will be returned (e.g. www.google.com/code=123456789).

The code is the exchanged for an access token.

My question is:

Can my app automatically get the code from the url and use it instead of the user having to copy and paste it in?

Thank you for reading!

Code:

```
TextField code = new TextField("Enter Code: ");

Button button = new Button("Click here to authenticate");

String callbackUrl = "http://reveal-it.appspot.com/oauthtest";

String clientID = "XXX";

String clientSecret = "XXX";

Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

InstagramService service = new 
InstagramAuthService().apiKey(clientId)
                      .apiSecret(clientSecret)
                      .callback(callbackUrl)
                      .build();

String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);



button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        getUI().getPage().open(authorizationUrl, "_blank");
        next();
    }   
});

public void next(){

    String verifierCode = code.getValue();

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(verifierCode);

    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);

    Instagram instagram = new Instagram(accessToken);

    UserInfo userInfo = instagram.getCurrentUserInfo();    

}
```

Step 1: Authenticate User
[image]

Step 2: Get URL with code attached at the back that user has to copy and paste into textfield
(This is a test url that prints the code)
[image]

Comment: You don't know how to get the token access automatically? im using jinstagram too and instead of copypasting the _authorizationUrl_ everytime i tried to access the url  with HttpURLConnection but it doesn't return someting like `www.mysite.com/instagram/oauth?code=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

These social platformas usually use oauth for login and right granting.
There exists a vaadin addon for this.

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/oauth-popup-add-on

Comment: I get "Sorry, requested add-on could not be found." when i click that link.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the link, no https needed.
If it still does not work, then search for the addon:
OAuth Popup Add-on